# What's with the space above <button> element?

Tags: html, css

I have a span with some text, and beneath it should be a textarea and a big square button, side by side. There should be *no vertical space* between the text area and the span, or between the button and the span. The textarea appears perfectly. The button, however, has about 15-20px of blank space above it, so that it appears quite a bit lower that the text area, rather than being nicely lined up. I told it to set padding and margin to 0px, so what the F?

```
<span class="notice">
Logged in as "ladygaga" (type message and hit ENTER or click SEND)
</span>

<textarea id="messagebox">
</textarea>
<button id="send">SEND</button>
```

And the CSS:

```
#messagebox
{
width:300px;
height:40px;
background-color:white;
border:2px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:green;
overflow:auto;
resize:none;
}

#send
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font-size:14px;
height:40px;
width:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
#send {
    vertical-align: top; 
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/YSHmE/2/

Answer (score 0):

I used *vertical-align: top*, but it still had the blank space.
Using *display: block* solved issue, no blank space.